# how can we use both tcpSerSock.listen(0) and tcpSerSock.send(str.encode(message)) at the same time

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, raspberry-pi, serversocket

my raspberry pi is the server and Im trying to send continuous message from rpi to android while recieving a command from client (android app),i really dont know if this is possible and how to do it is out of my reach and it is not a feedback message here is my code hope you will help me thank you.

```
import apptopi
from socket import *
from time import ctime
from nanpy import (ArduinoApi, SerialManager)

apptopi.setup()

connection = SerialManager()
a = ArduinoApi(connection = connection)

ctrCmd = ['Up','Down','Left','Right','Stop','Connect']

add = 0
add += 1
a = str(add) //**this is a sample that i want to send continously

HOST = ''
PORT = 21567
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)

tcpSerSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpSerSock.bind(ADDR)

tcpSerSock.listen(0)
tcpSerSock.send(str.encode(a))     <== i really don't know how to send 
                                      continuously


while True:
    print 'Waiting for connection'
    tcpCliSock,addr = tcpSerSock.accept()
    print '...connected from :', addr
    try:
            while True:
                    data = ''
                    data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZE)
                    if not data:
                            break
                    if data == ctrCmd[0]:
                            apptopi.forw()
                            print 'forward'
                    if data == ctrCmd[1]:
                            apptopi.back()
                            print 'backward'
                    if data == ctrCmd[2]:
                            apptopi.left()
                            print 'leftturn'
                    if data == ctrCmd[3]:
                            apptopi.right()
                            print 'rightturn'
                    if data == ctrCmd[4]:
                            apptopi.stp()
                            print 'stop'

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
            apptopi.close()
            GPIO.cleanup()
tcpSerSock.close();
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, but you cannot send on tcpSerSock like you're attempting to do, as it's not connected to anything, it's only listening for connections. I'm guessing you want to wait for the android client to connect, THEN send messages continuously to the client whilst simultaneously handling the ctrCmd messages from the client? I can show you how to do this if so.

Comment: yes i would be very happy if you can show me how it is done thank you

Comment: Sir Mackay can you help me, i really don't have the knowledge i kept on researching but i couldn't  make it pls help me. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK one approach is to use the `select()` function for this. There is information in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) about its operation.

As an example I've made a modified version of your program (see below). I don't have a raspberry pi, so that part of the code is commented out, but you can replace it as needed.

The example uses the timeout feature of `select()` to send "continuous" messages to clients whilst also monitoring them for incoming messages. You can adjust the message contents and timeout to whatever works for you.  NB you may also need to respond to client messages, as this code only sends data to clients after a timeout. Make whatever changes you need.

```
import sys
import socket
import select

ctrCmd = ['Up','Down','Left','Right','Stop','Connect']

HOST = ''
PORT = 21567
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)

tcpSerSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpSerSock.bind(ADDR)

tcpSerSock.listen(1)
print 'Waiting for connection'

sendInterval = 1.0  # interval(sec) for sending messages to connected clients 

rxset = [tcpSerSock]
txset = []
while 1:
    rxfds, txfds, exfds = select.select(rxset, txset, rxset, sendInterval)
    if rxfds:
        for sock in rxfds:
            if sock is tcpSerSock:
                # a client is connecting
                tcpCliSock, addr = tcpSerSock.accept()
                tcpCliSock.setblocking(0)
                rxset.append(tcpCliSock)
                print '...connected from :', addr
            else:
                # a client socket has data or has closed the connection
                try:
                    data = sock.recv(BUFSIZE)
                    if not data:
                        print "...connection closed by remote end"
                        rxset.remove(sock)
                        sock.close()
                    else:
                        if data == ctrCmd[0]:
                            #apptopi.forw()
                            print 'forward'
                        if data == ctrCmd[1]:
                            #apptopi.back()
                            print 'backward'
                        if data == ctrCmd[2]:
                            #apptopi.left()
                            print 'leftturn'
                        if data == ctrCmd[3]:
                            #apptopi.right()
                            print 'rightturn'
                        if data == ctrCmd[4]:
                            #apptopi.stp()
                            print 'stop'           
                except:
                    print "...connection closed by remote end"
                    rxset.remove(sock)
                    sock.close()
    else:
        # timeout - send data to any active client
        for sock in rxset:
            if sock is not tcpSerSock:
                sock.send("Hello!\n")
```

The simple client program I used to test this is here:

```
import sys
import socket
import time

ctrCmd = ['Up','Down','Left','Right','Stop','Connect']

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 21567
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)

tcpCliSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

tcpCliSock.connect(ADDR)
time.sleep(1)
for i in range(len(ctrCmd)):
    tcpCliSock.send(ctrCmd[i])
    time.sleep(1)
data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZE)
print data
tcpCliSock.close()
```

Hope this helps, best of luck.

Comment: Thank you very much sir I'm really grateful

Comment: hi sir i just finished edit my code in android and test it, the code is running but the message has sent but its not displaying it only display when i close the program, sir  what do you think is the problem ? sir what if it is not in a loop or close the sock after sending the message? what would be the best.

Comment: @MahilumJm can you edit your original question and add the new code at the end? I will take a look later.

Comment: sir i have not yet edited the code you sent, i test it and run but only display the message in android client when i close the program

Comment: @MahilumJm OK yes, that's how the test client program I wrote works. You need to rewrite it to interleave send and print.

Comment: ok sir mabe the problem is on the android client, im gonna review the code and hope it will display thank you very much sir AS Mackay

Comment: hi sir AS Mackay somehow my project has been change can i request your aid agian this time, im very thankful for everything that you did to me this is the revision of my project and i really need your help this is my problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513453/how-to-multi-thread-client-and-server-in-the-same-py please help me thank you very much